# How to access and pass third party cookie in adonis?

Tags: cookies, adonis.js

If I go with the request.cookies() in adonis it's given its own cookie value.

Comment: We need more information to provide helpful answer. Can you share cookie details, application url, ... thx

Comment: you use api or view also ?

Comment: I use nuxt in my frontend . Now I get one solution . I get the cookie from browser and pass it with my api.

Answer (score 0):

you need to try this one because in my case I use API so I get cookies using
`request.plainCookie()` it's work for me

Answer (score 0):

I follow one thing. I'm using nuxt.js in frontend and adonis.js in my backend. So,now I get the cookie from nuxt frontend and pass it with my API.

**My method**

```
async getCookie() {
        var cookieArr = document.cookie.split(";");
        for(var i = 0; i < cookieArr.length; i++) {
            var cookiePair = cookieArr[i].split("=");
            if('_fprom_ref' == cookiePair[0].trim()) {
                    this.cookieForm.ref_id = decodeURIComponent(cookiePair[1]);
            }
            if('_fprom_tid' == cookiePair[0].trim()) {
                this.cookieForm._fprom_tid = decodeURIComponent(cookiePair[1]);
            }

        }
        return 0;
    }
```

and API

```
<a :href="`${BASE_URL}googleLogin?reqParams=${this.fromhome}&ref_id=${this.cookieForm.ref_id}&_fprom_tid=${this.cookieForm._fprom_tid}`"> Test </a>
```